# Infinitesimal Ampère-Maxwell for (special/symmetric) current induced B field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

In a static magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$, which is induced by a static current density $\mathbf{j}$ the current density shall be zero for all points on the $z$ axis ($\mathbf{j}(0,0,z)=\mathbf{0} \; \forall z\in\mathbb{R}$) and obey a symmetry such that $\mathbf{B}$ is parallel to $z$ on the whole $x,y$ plane, and that $\mathbf{B}$ is vanishing quickly at large distances from the origin. And furthermore let us assume that all currents$\mathbf{j}$ off the (x,y) plane are identical to zero such that the $\mathbf{B}$ inducing currents  are all located at the $x,y$ plane.

The [Ampère-Maxwell law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) says that the path integral of $\mathbf{B}$ around a closed loop is proportional to the integral of the currents through a surface that is enclosed by the closed loop.

I have thought now about using the following integration loop of infinitesimal thickness in order to obtain the net current $\mathbf{j}_{tot}$ flowing in the $x,y$-plane according to the Ampère-Maxwell line integration:

[[image: Suggested infintesimal integration path for induced <span class=]$\mathbf{B}$ field" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83yz0.png)

Since $\mathbf{B}$ is perpendicular to $l_2$ at infinitesimal heights, the path integerals
$$ \int_{l_2} \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{d} l = \int_{l_4} \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{d} = 0l$$

since $\mathbf{B}$ is zero at infinte distances
$$ \int_{l_2} \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{d} l = 0$$
as well and we are left over with
$$ \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{d} l_1  = \mu_0\,\mathbf{j}\cdot d \mathbf{S}  $$ with $d \mathbf{S}$ being the rectangular area enclosed by the path.

Here I fail to understand how to interpret this expression, but my intuitive expectation fromthe construction of the integration path was that $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{0})$ will be proportional to the current in the plane
$$ I_0 = \mu_0 \int_0^{\infty} \mathbf{j}(0,0,z)\mathrm{d}z.$$

Using a circular loop as an example it seems this doesn't really work out, its merely that $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{0})$ gives the derivative of the path integral

$$I(z)=\mu_0 \int_{-\infty}^z B(0,0,z')\mathrm{d} z'$$

where

$$ I(\infty)=\mathbf{j}_{tot} $$

I still fail to clearly understand why $\mathbf{j}_{tot}$ cannot be determined after this integration scheme. Grateful for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

In your problem you have set a very specific restriction on your magnetic field, that it has only $z$ component, and you have required it to be true in the whole space (at least near $xy$ plane).

If you have a surface current, the component of the magnetic field *parralel* to the surface is guaranteed to be discontinuous. Ampère's circuital law shows that $B^{below}_{\parallel} - B^{above}_{\parallel} = \mu_0 j$, where $j$ is the surface current at given point. If $j$ is not zero, then at least at one side there must be non-zero magnetic field parallel to the surface.

It means that your system is not physically possible if $j\ne0$, as you require your parallel component to be zero at both sides (i. e. to be continuous). That's why you get your contradiction. The only possible solution then is $j=0$, no current, no magnetic field.

Comment: Regard an infinitely thin circular wire loop of radius $1$ m and current $1$A. I cannot see how $\mathbf{B}$ should have parallel components close to the plane of the loop.

Comment: It is not surface current then. But in such a case there is a component parallel to $xy$ plane near the wire and you'll have to pass it if you want to reach a region where $B=0$, like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCEZC.jpg Moreover, this field goes to infinity as you reach the wire.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! Genius!! Thank you very much (and welcome to PSE! on behalf of all users!)!!

Comment: Very welcome) Your question actually puzzled me for a while, but if a reliable law gives contradiction then there is probably contradiction in the problem statement. Usually it works. And thank you!